# '|' is not a postfix unary operator

Tags: swift, ios8, avaudiosession

I'm trying to add an options for `AVAudioSession` category:

```
let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    let options = .MixWithOthers.toRaw()|.DefaultToSpeaker.toRaw()
    if session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord,
      withOptions: options,
      error: &error){
...
}
```

I also tried

```
let options = .MixWithOthers|.DefaultToSpeaker
```

But it gives me the same error.

How can I combine those options?

Comment: Swift gave me this with the * sign, so I changed it and changed it back, now it works... it appears my problem wasn't swift directly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You actually need whitespace around the `|`.

```
let options = .MixWithOthers | .DefaultToSpeaker
```

Also, use `.rawValue` rather than `.rawValue()` (with newest xcode)

Answer (score 3):

The options have the type `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions`,
but in

```
let options = .MixWithOthers | .DefaultToSpeaker
```

the compiler cannot infer the type from the context. You can write

```
let options = AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.MixWithOthers | AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.DefaultToSpeaker
```

or

```
let options : AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions = .MixWithOthers | .DefaultToSpeaker
```

or

```
session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord,
            withOptions: .MixWithOthers | .DefaultToSpeaker , error: &error)
```